# Querying Amazon Athena with partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, partitioning, amazon-athena

Let's say I want to have partitions by some attribute and in each
partition I have couple of files with records in JSON (each file has more records).

I want to query them by some attribute that specifies when the record is created for specific attribute (give me all records created before some date).

Do I need to sort records in file by date to get better performance?

Will the Athena just scan from first record to the last one and than
give me the result?

Comment: your question is unclear -- could you please Edit your question and provide more information about what you are doing and what difficulties you have encountered? Some examples would also help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Athena partitioning is purely based on the S3 folder structure. Apart from that, all queries are running from first to the last element.

If you need some sort of partitioning, you can only define them via S3 directories and then manage them (manually or automatically depending on the folder format)

Here some more info on partitions:

[Partitioning Data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html)

Comment: if the s3 folder format is yyyy/mm/dd, how to make a partition out of it in Athena?

Comment: you need to include a column name along with the values to get it working.
e.g. y=<yyyy>/m=<mm>/d=<dd> then register partitions under the table using three consecutive columns using alter table add partition y=<yyyy>, m=<mm>,d=<dd>. And ensure data is landed in the innermost hierarchy d=<dd>

Comment: @nitinr708 if there are situations to query between partitions, say 29th June to 3rd July, what kind of approach is suggested for the query?

Answer (score -1):

```
dt between '29-06-2022' and '03-07-2022'
```